# checkbox..setOnCheckedChangeListener() doesn't work in fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-studio

the method .`setOnCheckedChangeListener(MyFragmentList.this)` is underline in red by `IDE`...i don't understand what parameter i must pass to method `setOnCheckedChangeListener` in `Fragment`.
Thanks.

ADAPTER CODE:

```
public class PlanetAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Planet>

{

  private List<Planet> planetList;
  private Context context;
  ArrayList<Planet> objects;


  public  PlanetAdapter(List<Planet> planetList, Context context) {
      super(context, R.layout.single_listview_item, planetList);
      this.planetList = planetList;
      this.context = context;
  }




    public  class PlanetHolder  {
      public TextView planetName;
      public TextView distView;
      public TextView valuta;
      public CheckBox chkBox;
      public EditText edit;
      public String quantità;



  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

View row = convertView;
      PlanetHolder holder = null;
      if (row == null) {
          LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
          row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_listview_item, parent, false);
          holder = new PlanetHolder();
          holder.planetName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name);
          holder.distView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.dist);
          holder.valuta = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.valuta);
          holder.chkBox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.chk_box);
          holder.edit = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.editText);
          holder.edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          holder.edit.setEnabled(false);
          row.setTag(holder);
      } else {
          holder = (PlanetHolder) row.getTag();
      }
      final Planet p = planetList.get(position);

      holder.chkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(MyListFragment.this);
      final PlanetHolder finalHolder = holder;
      holder.chkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              if (finalHolder.chkBox.isChecked()) {
                  finalHolder.edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  finalHolder.edit.setEnabled(true);
                  finalHolder.edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                      @Override
                      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                      }

                      @Override
                      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                      }

                      @Override
                      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                          p.setQuantità(finalHolder.edit.getText().toString().trim());

                      }
                  });
              } else {
                  finalHolder.edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                  finalHolder.edit.setEnabled(false);
                  finalHolder.edit.setText(null);
              }
          }
      });
      holder.planetName.setText(p.getName());
      holder.distView.setText("" + p.getDistance());
      holder.valuta.setText(""+p.getValuta());
      holder.chkBox.setChecked(p.isSelected());
      holder.chkBox.setTag(p);
      holder.edit.setEnabled(false);

      return row;
  }


  ArrayList<Planet> getBox() {
      ArrayList<Planet> box = new ArrayList<Planet>();
      for (Planet p : planetList) {
          if (p.selected)
              box.add(p);
      }
      return box;
  }


}
```

ACTIVITY:

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity  {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().

                replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, new MyListFragment()).commit();



    }


}
```

FRAGMENT:

```
public class MyListFragment extends Fragment implements
        android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<Planet> planetList;
    PlanetAdapter plAdapter;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list2, container, false);
        Button mButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            showResult(v);

            }
        });
        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list2, container, false);
        return  rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        lv = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.listview);
        displayPlanetList();
    }


    private void displayPlanetList() {

        planetList = new ArrayList<Planet>();
        planetList.add(new Planet("Margherita", 6, "€"));
        planetList.add(new Planet("Diavola", 7,"€"));
        planetList.add(new Planet("Bufalina", 5,"€"));
        planetList.add(new Planet("Marinara", 5,"€"));
        planetList.add(new Planet("Viennese", 4,"€"));

        plAdapter = new PlanetAdapter(planetList, getContext());
        lv.setAdapter(plAdapter);
    }



    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        int pos = lv.getPositionForView(buttonView);
        if (pos != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
            Planet p = planetList.get(pos);
            p.setSelected(isChecked);



        /*Toast.makeText(
                getActivity(),
                "Clicked on Planet: " + p.getName() + ". State: is "
                        + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
        }

    }


    public void showResult(View v) {
        String result = "Selected Product are :";
        int totalAmount=0;

        for (Planet p : plAdapter.getBox()) {
            if (p.selected){
                //System.out.println("pizza selezionata: " + p.name);

                    //System.out.println("nessuna pizza selezionata: ");



                result += "\n" + p.name+" "+p.distance+"€"+"q.tà :"+p.getQuantità();
                //if (p.quantità.equals("") && p.quantità.equals(null) ){
                //System.out.println("leggo questo record:"+p.name + " " + p.distance + " " + p.quantità );

                //System.out.println("leggo questo p.getquatità :"+p.quantità );
                //}
                //else{
                //System.out.println("leggo questo in p.quantità: " + p.getQuantità());
                int quantitaInt= Integer.parseInt(p.getQuantità() );
                totalAmount+=p.distance * quantitaInt;

                //}
            }
        }
      Toast.makeText(getActivity(), result + "\n" + "Total Amount:=" + totalAmount, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //System.out.println("leggo result e total amount: " + result + " " + totalAmount);



        //Integer.toString(totalAmount);
    //  Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), TwoFragment.class);
        /*i.putExtra("NomeDati1", result);
        i.putExtra("NomeDati2", String.valueOf(totalAmount));
        startActivity(i);
*/

    }

}
```

Edit:

I get the following error when i use the solution by @Nathanael

[image]

Comment: `holder.chkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(MyListFragment.this);` Why can't you do this in your fragment and pass `this`? Or add the listener at that very spot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in an implementation of `CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener`.

```
holder.chkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // Do what you need to do
        }
});
```

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener)) is the API reference for `CheckedChangeListener`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the approach because when you are using checkbox in adapter you should have a boolean in your adapter list item object and all the check for checked true and false should handled in 'getView' and on check changed only item.setChecked should change see the code below this is only sample code you can do it using viewholder also

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private List<MyItem> items;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public MyAdapter(Context context, List<MyItem> items) {
    this.items = items;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public MyItem getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    MyItem item=getItem(position);
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapteritem,null);
    CheckBox checkBox=(CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.chb);
    TextView txt=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    if(item.isChecked)
    {
        txt.setText(item.title+" Selected");
    }else{
        txt.setText(item.title+" Not Selected");
    }
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            item.isChecked=isChecked;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    return view;
}

public class MyItem {
    public boolean isChecked = false;
    public String title;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> for fragment first we need to implements android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener see this example

```
public class TabAdvertiser extends Fragment implements android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

CheckBox mCbShowPwd;
EditText userName,password;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, container, false);

    userName=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.input_email);
    password=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.input_password);
    // get the show/hide password Checkbox
    mCbShowPwd = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.cbShowPwd);
    mCbShowPwd.setOnCheckedChangeListener(TabAdvertiser.this);
    return view;
}
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    // checkbox status is changed from uncheck to checked.
    if (!isChecked) {
        // show password
        password.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
    } else {
        // hide password
        password.setTransformationMethod(HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance());
    }
}
```

}